# Reading FeignClient url from application.yaml not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign, property-placeholder

I am trying to read the Feign client url from application.yaml, I am not using ribbon. Ribbon worked before now I migrated to spring boot 3.1.4 and spring cloud 2022.0.3

```
@FeignClient(name = "new-common-service", url = "${spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.new-common-service.url}")
public interface NewCommonServiceClient {
@GetMapping(value = "/test")
ResponseEntity<?> testRequest();

}
```

In application yaml

```
cloud:
    openfeign:
      client:
        config:
          new-common-service:
          url: localhost:9090/serve
```

It is showing error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: http://${cloud.openfeign.client.config.new-common-service.url} is malformed
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Illegal character found in host: '{'

how to fix this issue

I expect FeignClient url value to be read from the application yaml file

Comment: Remove the url from annotation and put it in your properties: spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.new-common-service.url=https://yoururl.com

Comment: I removed and started and it is now showing the below error ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.cloud.openfeign.client.config.new-common-service' to org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientProperties$FeignClientConfiguration:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientProperties$FeignClientConfiguration]

Comment: After restarting my machine and opened my STS and it worked. FeingClient interface is taking url from application yaml file. Thanks @GuyT